# How to set up 2 SSL cert on a single webpage

Tags: apache, ssl, security, ssl-certificate, web

I am running an Apache web server and I have supposed to put 2 SSL cert on a single website. Is this possible? how can I do this? I read the apache user manual and it says I only can have 1 SSL cert for a single IP and port.

Comment: having two different SSL certs on one website/URL is a security issue... what is it you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm placing my site with a CDN, and I want them to cache my static content like banners and css. and I don't want dynamic secured data from my side to be cached. but I dont want the security pop up on browsers that warn me that there are content not on ssl. so my idea is to use 2 ssl cert for both dynamic and static content.

Comment: then you need to setup two subdomains (one for static, one for dynamic content) with a wildcard cert... then you setup the CDN for the static subdomain only

Comment: hey Yahia, so for each of the sub domain, i will need a ssl cert?

Comment: no - you use just one cert - but this must be a "wildcard cert" for your domain...

Comment: okok. i will google about this. thanks man for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the comments from the OP:

Setup two subdomains - one for static/to be CDN'd content and one for dynamic/not to be CDN'd content.

Get + setup a "wildcard cert" for your domain i.e. a cert for "*.yourdomain.com"... these are a bit more expensive but exactly for your situation...

Comment: Yahia, what if they are of 2 different domains? the static content are using absolute path [https://edge.cdn.provider.com/companyname/style.css] instead of [/style.css]

Comment: if the domain itself is different then there is no wildcard cert to achieve that... your CDN should have valid https URL with his own cert for this case to use by you... this would make your page content still completely secure/SSL with no "mixed content" warnings...

Comment: thanks Yahia! you are of great help. sorry i can't vote up cause I've only got 7 rep points

Comment: You do not necessarily need a full wildcard cert, you can get a cert with a list of the domain names it is valid for. I forget what the CAs call this but it is usually much cheaper than a wildcard cert for 5 or so domains.

Answer (score 0):

As Yahia points out. A wildcard cert is an option. They are also expensive.

You can certainly have multiple named SSL certs on your server for images.domain.com and static.domain.com or whatever named sites you want and that is not a security issue. In fact, that is considered more secure than a wildcard cert.

It is true that you can only have one named cert per IP. Because SSL certs are bound to the IP in the web server config. So you would need to have multiple IP addresses on the server hosting the sites. If the dynamic and static content are already on different machines, then you're set there, but it sounds like they are on the same machine.

That doesn't mean that the ports need to be different between the site. You can have both 123.45.67.89 and 123.45.67.88 listening on the same port (443 in this case) on the same machine.

Here is a post I found that looks like it describes the config pretty well.

http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Multiple_SSL_Virtual_Hosts